# Pyspark how to avoid explode for groups in the top and nested structure (code optimalisation)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nested, explode

### Problem

I'd like to compute some stats from request data grouped by values in top layer and values in nested layer. The main problem with explode-join and 3x groupby is **the code with big data (100GB) is too slow**.

Sample data:

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as T

rows = [
    {"id": 1, "typeId": 1, "items":[
        {"itemType": 1,"flag": False,"event": None},
        {"itemType": 3,"flag": True,"event":[{"info1": ""},{"info1": ""}]},
        {"itemType": 3,"flag": True,"event":[{"info1": ""},{"info1": ""}]},
    ]},
    {"id": 2, "typeId": 2, "items":None},
    {"id": 3, "typeId": 1, "items":[
        {"itemType": 1,"flag": False,"event": None},
        {"itemType": 6,"flag": False,"event":[{"info1": ""}]},
        {"itemType": 6,"flag": False,"event":None},
    ]},
    {"id": 4, "typeId": 2, "items":[
        {"itemType": 1,"flag": True,"event":[{"info1": ""}]},
    ]},
    {"id": 5, "typeId": 3, "items":None},
]

schema = T.StructType([
   T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType(), False),
   T.StructField("typeId", T.IntegerType()),
   T.StructField("items", T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
           T.StructField("itemType", T.IntegerType()),
           T.StructField("flag", T.BooleanType()),
           T.StructField("event", T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
                   T.StructField("info1", T.StringType()),
           ]))),
       ])), True),
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df.printSchema()
```

their structure:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- typeId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- itemType: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- flag: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- event: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- info1: string (nullable = true)
```

I'd like to perform these calculations for each `typeid` and by `items.itemtype`:

- total of rows (requests)
- total of rows (requests) if contains some item
- total of rows (requests) if contains some item with (items.flag==True)
- total of items
- total of flaged items (items.flag==True)
- total of events on items (sum(size("items.event")))

### Code

Get total of request for every `typeId` is simple, in real analysis `layer1_groups` contain more category columns:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

layer1_groups = ["typeId"]

# get count for groups in top layer
totaldf = df.groupby(layer1_groups).agg(F.count(F.lit(1)).alias("requests"))
```

For future computation (e.g. ratio with computed number on nested group), join these numbers to original dataframe:

```py
df = df.join(totaldf, layer1_groups)
```

explode `items` to allow grouping by nested `items.itemType`

```py
exploded_df = df.withColumn("I", F.explode_outer("items")).select("*","I.*").drop("items","I")
# add another info of item (number of events)
exploded_df = exploded_df.withColumn("eSize", F.greatest(F.size("event"), F.lit(0)))
```

grouping stats for every request (groupby `"id"`) to obtain, because in future computation I want to count requests only if has flaged items, etc.:

```py
layer2_groups = ["itemType"]

each_requests = exploded_df.groupby(["id", *layer1_groups, *layer2_groups]).agg(
    F.first("requests").alias("requests"),
    F.count(F.lit(1)).alias("ItemCount"),
    F.sum(F.col("flag").cast(T.ByteType())).alias("fItemCount"),
    F.sum("eSize").alias("eCount"),
)
```

Finish groups are without the `"id"` group:

```py
# results without layer1 "id" to obtain resulsts
requests_results = each_requests.groupby([*layer1_groups, *layer2_groups]).agg(
    F.first("requests").alias("requests"),
    F.count_if(F.col("ItemCount")>0).alias("requestsWithItems"),
    F.count_if(F.col("fItemCount")>0).alias("requestsWith_fItems"),
    F.sum("ItemCount").alias("ItemCount"),
    F.sum("fItemCount").alias("fItemCount"),
    F.sum("eCount").alias("eCount"),
).show()
```

result is:

```
+------+--------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+------+
|typeId|itemType|requests|requestsWithItems|requestsWith_fItems|ItemCount|fItemCount|eCount|
+------+--------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+------+
|     1|       1|       2|                2|                  0|        2|         0|     0|
|     1|       3|       2|                1|                  1|        2|         2|     4|
|     1|       6|       2|                1|                  0|        2|         0|     1|
|     2|       1|       2|                1|                  1|        1|         1|     1|
|     2|    NULL|       2|                1|                  0|        1|      NULL|     0|
|     3|    NULL|       1|                1|                  0|        1|      NULL|     0|
+------+--------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+------+
```

### Whole code

Gist: https://gist.github.com/vanheck/bfcadf7396d765ddd2fff5f544fd7cf2

## Question

Is there some way to make faster this code? Or can I avoid `explode` function to obtain these stats?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explode to get the statistics that you need. I tried this below on my local and it worked. I have pasted my result - please adjust as per your requirement.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Function to count items based on a condition
def count_items_condition(col, condition):
    return F.size(F.expr(f"filter({col}, item -> {condition})"))

# Function to sum the size of "event" arrays in "items"
def sum_events_size(col):
    return F.expr(f"aggregate({col}, 0, (acc, item) -> acc + size(item.event))")

# Add calculations as new columns
df = df.withColumn("total_requests", F.lit(1)) \
       .withColumn("total_requests_with_item", F.when(F.size("items") > 0, 1).otherwise(0)) \
       .withColumn("total_requests_with_item_flag_true", count_items_condition("items", "item.flag")) \
       .withColumn("total_items", F.size("items")) \
       .withColumn("total_flagged_items", count_items_condition("items", "item.flag")) \
       .withColumn("total_events_on_items", sum_events_size("items"))

# Group by typeId and sum the calculations
result = df.groupBy("typeId") \
           .agg(
               F.sum("total_requests").alias("total_requests"),
               F.sum("total_requests_with_item").alias("total_requests_with_item"),
               F.sum("total_requests_with_item_flag_true").alias("total_requests_with_item_flag_true"),
               F.sum("total_items").alias("total_items"),
               F.sum("total_flagged_items").alias("total_flagged_items"),
               F.sum("total_events_on_items").alias("total_events_on_items")
           )

result.show()

+------+--------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+
|typeId|total_requests|total_requests_with_item|total_requests_with_item_flag_true|total_items|total_flagged_items|total_events_on_items|
+------+--------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+
|     1|             2|                       2|                                 2|          6|                  2|                    2|
|     2|             2|                       1|                                 0|          0|                  0|                    1|
|     3|             1|                       0|                                -1|         -1|                 -1|                 NULL|
+------+--------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Great, excellent resolution!

Comment: Problem there is, this is grouped only for typeId (top layer group). But I need groups `["typeId", "items.itemType"]`.